# Set onClickListener into custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

Hello at all the community,
i've this adapter with 2 `button` and 2 `textview`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, null);
        holder.result = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.value);
        holder.add = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        holder.subtract = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.subtract);         

        myObject = getItem(position);
        holder.result.setText(myObject.result);
        holder.value.setText(myObject.value);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder)view.getTag();
    }

    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }           
    });

    return view;
}
```

Now my question is: if I want that when the user press on add button set the text of the `textview` with (for example) 5 how can i do this? If I put into the `onCLick` method

`holder.result.setText("My text")` set the text of the last textview and not the correspond textview of the selected row item (I disabled the click on the listview with):

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your code in the `getView` method inside the adapter and remember to use references to the current `Button`/`TextVeiw` so that each `Button` would correspond to that specific `TextView`

P.S. I found something with your code check this out:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, null);
        holder.result = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.value);
        holder.add = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        holder.subtract = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.subtract); 

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder)view.getTag();
    }       

    myObject = getItem(position);
    holder.result.setText(myObject.result);
    holder.value.setText(myObject.value);
    final TextView tv = holder.result;

    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tv.setText("bla bla");          
            }           
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: The method getView is already in the adapter! For convenience, I posted only the getView method. Which references do you speak?

Comment: The onClick method is already into getView method. What do you mean? I don't understand. Plese, better explain.

Comment: What I meant is post the actual code you had in `OnClickListener` but Check the updated answer, I am guessing you used `final` `holder.result.setText` inside the `OnClickListener`, while u should use `final TextView` there

Answer (score 0):

You mixed something up, the getItem has to be below the view creation stuff. First create the view, then set the values.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
if(view == null) {
    holder = new Holder();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, null);
    holder.result = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    holder.value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.value);
    holder.add = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);
    holder.subtract = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.subtract);         
    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (Holder)view.getTag();
}

myObject = getItem(position);
holder.result.setText(myObject.result);
holder.value.setText(myObject.value);

holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

     //What should happen here?

    }           
});

return view;
```

}

Comment: In the onClick method i should set a text to the corresponding TextView. What are the differences between my and your code?

Comment: Views in a listView get recycled, that's why you use the holder pattern to have fast access to the views. Your code worked only for the first time, when you created the view, the second time you retrieved the holder, but you didn't set the new values.